# MySQL ORDER BY 2 Columns with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table, let's call it `buildings`.

```
building_code  |  city  |  phone
1              |  A     |  +1 212 444 555
2              |  B     |  +2 333 444 555
3              |  C     |  +3 222 234 122
4              |  A     |  +1 212 555 444
```

So each city has a few buildings. What I'm trying to do now is select the city and phone number from the buildings. However, I want to sort city by Ascending and also if a city has multiples buildings (example A), then I also want to sort the phone number by Descending order.

The end-result would be

```
city  |  phone
A     |  +1 212 555 444
A     |  +1 212 444 555
B     |  +2 333 444 555
C     |  +3 222 234 122
```

So the query I tried is `SELECT city, phone FROM buildings ORDER BY city ASC`
This works and sorts city name in Ascending order. However, I am not sure how to order the phone in descending order.

I tried `SELECT city, phone FROM buildings ORDER BY city ASC, IF(COUNT(city) > 1, phone, '') DESC;` and it gave me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT city, phone FROM buildings ORDER BY city ASC, phone DESC
```

as simple as that. See it working live [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c8e1a/1/0)

Comment: Haha, I can't believe this. I really overcomplicated things here. Can you explain to me the logic behind?

Comment: There's no need for a condition on `phone DESC` because it'll act the same whether there are 0, 1 or more rows.

Comment: @nTuply *Can you explain to me the logic behind?* `ORDER BY city ASC, phone DESC` means: sort by city in ascending order, if a bunch of records have the same city, sort within this group (only) by phone in descending order.

Comment: Ah, others were faster in explaining. Thanks guys.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT city, phone FROM buildings ORDER BY city ASC, phone DESC;
```